# Bracha of leshev basuccah sitting down

Tags: halacha, blessing, mitzvah, sukkot

The Mishna Berura says in three places (that I know of) that every birchas hamizvah must be said standing up (סי' ח' ס"ק ב', סי' תפט שעה"צ ס"ק ז', וסי' תקפה ס"ק א-ב). If this is true, why doesn't anyone stand for the bracha of leshev basuccah other than by kiddush, like when they are having a snack over chol hamo'ed?

Perhaps the reason is that without sitting there's no kviyus and you shouldn't be making any bracha, which would not be the case on Shabbos/Yom Tov when it's muchrach that you'll stay for the seuda (see Aruch Hashulchan O"C 166:1)?

Any insights and/or mareh mekomos would be greatly appeciated.

Comment: Maybe similar to pesach night ;-)

Comment: Do you stand for maror at the seder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch in [643:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.643.2?lang=bi) says one should say it standing. The Rama comments that we say it sitting down.

The Pri Migadim in [Eishel Avraham 8:2](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41248&st=&pgnum=40) (towards the end) says that the reason we say it sitting down is because it’s like challah, and it’s more like Birchas hanenin.

The Pnei Yehoshua in [Megilla 21A](https://www.sefaria.org/Penei_Yehoshua_on_Megillah.21a.3?lang=bi) says that if the mitzvah itself can be said sitting then there bracha can be said sitting as well.

Comment: That's a misleading representation of the first source in my opinion. They are discussing how to say kiddush, not how the leshev blessing is always said.

Comment: @DoubleAA and yet the Pri Migadim understands it to refer to leishev as well. The Shulchan Aruch clearly mentions it as well, to be said standing, together with kiddush

Comment: I didn't say it's an irrelevant source